# Insert selected values to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure where I select values and want insert into table

```
SELECT 
    @uid = arf.uid, @report_format = arf.report_format,
    @report_serno = arf.report_serno
FROM 
    dbo.alert_report_format AS arf 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.users AS u ON arf.uid = u.serno 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.alert_reports AS ar ON arf.report_serno = ar.serno
```

Insert in table :

```
INSERT INTO reports 
VALUES (NULL, @uid, @subject, @body, @report_format, 100, @report_serno, 0, NULL, 10, GETDATE())
```

In select I have 5 values, but when I insert to another table onle inserted last selected value, I want insert to table all values what I have in my select, how do this without cursors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO reports 
SELECT null,arf.uid, @subject, @body, arf.report_format,  100,arf.report_serno,0,NULL,10,GETDATE()
FROM dbo.alert_report_format AS arf 
INNER JOIN dbo.users AS u ON arf.uid = u.serno 
INNER JOIN dbo.alert_reports AS ar ON arf.report_serno = ar.serno
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use something like

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2,.... ColumnN)
SELECT C1,C2,... CN
FRom MyTable
```

Have a look at [Inserting data from other tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#OtherTables)

Also have a look at [INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)